# How to use NgbAccordion in Angular project

Tags: angular

I am trying to add an accordion to my Angular 2 project. I think I have made all necessary changes. But still accordion is not visible. Can anyone tell me what amI missing?

package.json

```
...
dependencies: {
   "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
   "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
   "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
   "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.25",
   "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.4",
}
...
```

app/shared/ngb-accordion/accordion.ts

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, ViewChild, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'sse-accordion',
    templateUrl: './accordion.html'
})

export class Accordion implements OnInit {
    panelOneTitle: string = 'Device';
    panelTwoTitle: string = 'Connector';

    @ViewChild('acc') acc: NgbModule;

    ngOnInit(): void {

    }
}
```

app/shared/ngb-accordion/accordion.html

```
<div>
    <ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="ngb-panel-0">
        <ngb-panel title="{{panelOneTitle}}">
            <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
            aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.
            </ng-template>
        </ngb-panel>
        <ngb-panel>
            <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
            <span>&#9733; <b>Fancy</b> title &#9733;</span>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
            aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.
            </ng-template>
        </ngb-panel>
        <ngb-panel title="Disabled" [disabled]="true">
            <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
            aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.
            </ng-template>
        </ngb-panel>
    </ngb-accordion>
</div>
```

Parent component in which accordion is being embedded:
app/movies/movie-detail.ts

```
import { Accordion } from '../shared/ngb-accordion/accordion';

@Component({
    selector: 'movie-dialog',
    template: require('./movie-detail.html'),
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    styles: [require('./movie-detail.scss')]
})

export class MovieDetail {

    @ViewChild('detailPanel') detailPanel: Accordion;
    ngOnInit(): void {
        // detailPanel.panelTitle = service.movie.title;
    }
}

app/movies/movie-detail.html

    <div>
        <div><accordion></accordion></div>
    </div>
```

shared/shared.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    NgbModule,
],
declaration: [Accordion]

})
```

Comment: is there any error showing?

Comment: @sainu I am getting error as : "EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: ctorParameters.map is not a function"

Comment: I figured it is due to some version mismatch among angular, bootstrap and ng-bootstrap. But I am not sure what is the straight forward way to know the compatible version. Do I need hit and trial by changing 3 package's versions and try or any other quicker way is there?

Comment: The dependencies for the latest version are listed here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started. The angular version that ng-bootstrap depends on is in its package.json file. The breaking changes section of the changelog (https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) tells where the minimal version of a dependency (angular or Bootstrap) changes. When ng-bootstrap is released in final version, every version should have its own documentation, listing its dependencies.